# Exporting from digiKam album view to local filesystem?

Tags: images

In the album view I am able to select multiple photos and have the option to export to many many different types of destinations under the 'Export' menu (Dropbox, Flickr, Google Drive, Imgur, etc.), but I don't see a mechanism to export directly to the local filesystem.

How can I export multiple photos to the local filesystem using a similar export wizard that lets me specify output format, resolution, and file naming?

digiKam version 4.14.0

Answer (score 1):

**Copy and Paste**

Not exactly what you were asking for, but I was looking for a simple »export to folder« as well.

In the Edit menu there is Cut, Copy and Paste. So I used Copy with my selected files, opened Finder and pasted into the target directory. This copied the file selection as it is. Maybe this helps. It is a simple solution anyway.

(Drag and drop worked, however, I had no chance just to copy, it always moved. I have no clue why.)

Comment: drag and drop works to copy for me (it may help that i'm trying to copy to removable media?) but when i copy, nothing shows in in the file manager as being able to be pasted

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but my original photos were in RAW format and copying them to a new folder doesn't help.  In my case, I used the Batch Queue Manager in digiKam to convert my pictures to PNG format and place them in another directory.  Now I can upload my photos to Amazon (or whatever) without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I too struggled until I added the kipi plugins using software manager - that gives you loads of export options including a local folder